# How to upload file AND model using Web API?

Tags: asp.net, rest, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Basically I'm trying to upload an image along with an enum using Web API 2.

Here's the controller signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public UploadResponseVm Upload([FromBody]ResImageType type)
{
```

The thing is, whenever I try to post a multipart form (with a file and a type) I get a 415 error:

> {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is
>   not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'ResImageType' from content with media type
>   'multipart/form-data'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

I have even added the following to my startup.cs class:

```
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

How can I upload a model along with a file using a web api controller?

Answer (score 0):

There is no formatter that could handle/relate to your `ResImageType` object. I have once solved a similar problem without a formatter by using a parameter-less method and have processed the data inside the method. For example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

            string upDir= "PathOfDirectory";

            MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(upDir);                
            MultipartFileStreamProvider multipartFileStreamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

            // Loop through files.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                // Save filepaths to DB or do something else
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Similar solution from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)

Another possibility is to create a DTO-like class that is used to transfer the object and use a formatter, for example [MultipartDataMediaFormatter](https://github.com/iLexDev/ASP.NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter) seems legit (haven't tried).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add media and enum at the same time by adding content type in header request.

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Then try to access file and enum

```
[HttpPost]
public UploadResponseVm Upload()
{
            //Get enum type
            var enumkey = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "enumkey");
            var enumType = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[enumkey]).ToEnum<ResImageType>();

            //Access files
            var postedFileLst = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.GetMultiple("fileKey").ToList();
}
```

Use Extension Method to convert to enum

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this int param)
{
            var info = typeof(T);
            if (info.IsEnum)
            {
                T result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), param.ToString(), true);
                return result;
            }

            return default(T);
}
```

Also verify using curl

```
curl --location --request POST '{{hostname}}/api/media/addmedia' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--form 'BookLogos=@/path/to/file' \
--form 'enumkey=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example will solve the issue if you have the following code changes.

Put `[FromForm]` with parameters

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> Create([FromForm] CreateEmployeeCommand command)
```

and in model

```
public class CreateEmployeeCommand
{
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
    public string AnyData { get; set; }
}
```

Use JS `FormData` object to `POST` data to the controller